Spring boot 3.24 spring allow circular references
I have a Spring boot app 3.2.4 with java 21 with some circular references and I wanted to use the profile statement spring.main.allow-circular-references=true but it does not work. I do not know why? Has it been disabled? I see also the IntelliJ does not suggest it when typing like for other settings

So even setup, sometimes it throws some action as to add @Primary if several implementations and other actions including to update IDE and configuration. But another point to solve it with its usage is to find one class with one field from that particular circle and avoid its usage in some way to break that cycle. Then repeat until the circle decreased to zero. Such property there where that implementation helps for improper designs by information message even if not succeeded. If modular one to rebuild submodules also.

However this argument spring.main.allow-circular-references and this message Despite circular references being allowed, the dependency cycle between beans could not be broken. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle. shows that there are 2 or three types of such cycles.

It is very difficult to say what the issue is without seeing the code but to answer your question Spring boot definitely still allows spring.main.allow-circular-references=true.
Here is the Common Application Properties list of Spring Boot 3.2.4 which still contains spring.main.allow-circular-references.
Also, its always considered bad design to have a circular references but if you must have circular references in your code for some reason you can always use @Lazy.
Example:
@Component
public class CircularDependencyA {

private CircularDependencyB circB;

   @Autowired
   public CircularDependencyA(@Lazy CircularDependencyB circB) {
       this.circB = circB;
   }
}

